# Simpson's Rule Equivalent for Line Integrals?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I recently coded a program that can estimate a line integral with respect to arc length.
For example:

$$\int_Cf(x, y) dS$$

Where C is represented by the parametric equations x(t) and y(t), a ≤ t ≤ b.  To estimate this, I started by creating the variable $\delta = \frac {b-a}{n}$ where n is a large number.  I then made the sum (from t=a to t=b by the increment of $\delta$) by averaging two consecutive points of f(x, y) along the path C using $\delta$ as the increment to find the "height" of the rectangle and multiplied it by the "base", which I found using $\sqrt{(x(t)-x(t+\delta))^2*(y(t)-y(t+\delta))^2}$.

Is it possible to estimate line integrals like this with a modified version of Simpson's Rule?

Comment: Why not just write the line integral as a (regular) integral in terms of the parameterization and use Simpson's rule on that?

Comment: I would have some trouble handling the derivatives.  It may be possible though, thanks.

Comment: @Argon : You want to estimate an integral, the fact that it is a line integral or a non-line integral doesn't matter ; once you know that the number you want to estimate is a number, the rest is just technique ; as long as you know theoretically that it'll converge, the background behind the number doesn't matter if you can approximate successfully enough.

Comment: @Argon: why is it $\sqrt{(x(t)-x(t+\delta))^2*(y(t)-y(t+\delta))^2}$ not $\sqrt{(x(t)-x(t+\delta))^2 + (y(t)-y(t+\delta))^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that dealing with $f^\prime(t)$ and $g^\prime(t)$ when you're unable or unwilling to compute analytic derivatives is what's giving you trouble; there are [a number of numerical differentiation methods](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64302/64306#64306) you can use along with Simpson's rule (but methinks you really should be using Gaussian quadrature instead). On the other hand, there is a simple strategem due to [J.C. Nash](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=GCglAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA219) for estimating derivatives, based on the central difference approximation

$$f^{\prime}(x)\approx\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

The trick here is to choose $h$ to be small, but not too small; Nash's suggestion is to use $h=\sqrt{\varepsilon}\left(|x|+\sqrt{\varepsilon}\right)$ where $\varepsilon$ is machine epsilon. This should be good enough for most purposes.