# Proving that: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} :|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, proof-writing

Suppose $x>0$ and we have function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ how can we show $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} :|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq \frac{1}{n+1}$$ I need a hint to show this property .Thanks in advance . I tried for $n=1 ,2$  by finding maximum of $|f'| ,|f''|$ but I get stuck to show for $n$

Comment: I was wondering if you could bring this into a complex integral of some sort, and bring Cauchy's estimates into it. That's all I wondered for now, but I'll get back if I find anything more.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Oh i was wondering whether we can use the general leibniz rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule and use some elementary inequalities to get an estimate :D

Comment: Yes, this is also very interesting. I will look through it, and see if we can come up with some induction argument.

Comment: Hello maybe it could help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130192/method-for-estimating-the-nth-derivative .Have a good day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $$ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} =  \int_{0}^{1} \cos(tx) dt$$

with proper justifications (differentiation under the integral sign) you may derive

$$\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{(n)} = \int_{0}^{1} t^n \cos(tx+n\pi/2) dt$$ which immediately yields the wanted estimate.

Answer (score 2):

See that,  $\displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{x} =f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-itx} dt$ Then 
$$|f^{(n)}(x)| =\left|\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} (-it)^ne^{-itx} dt\right|  \le\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} |t|^n dt=\int_0^1t^n\,dt=\frac1{n+1}.$$

Comment: This is basically Gabriel's answer.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496146/let-fx-dfrac-sin-xx-prove-that-fnx-frac1n1/2496196#2496196

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Combine the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) to the following inequality :

$$\frac{1}{2n+1}\geq\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}|\frac{sin((n+0.5)x)}{sin(0.5x)}|\geq \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}|\frac{sin((n+0.5)x)}{0.5x}|$$

And use the same inductive reasoning as Emil Artin for this proof related to the Gamma function .