# Let $f(x) =\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ prove that : $|f^{(n)}(x)|<\frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, contest-math

let $x>0$ And $f(x) =\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ prove that for every $n$ :

$$|f^{(n)}(x)|<\frac{1}{n+1}$$

---

for $f^{(1)}$ we have :

$$\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}<\frac{1}{2}$$

---

for $f^{(2)}$ we have :

$$\frac{x^2(-x\sin x)-2x(x\cos x-\sin x)}{x^2}<\frac{1}{3}$$

Now what ?

Comment: This is IMC 2014 day 2 problem 3: http://www.imc-math.org.uk/index.php?year=2014&item=problems You'll find some solutions there.

Answer (score 8):

$$f(x)=\int_0^1\cos(tx)\,dt.$$
Write $c(y)=\cos y$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^1 t^n c^{(n)}(tx)\,dt.$$
As $c^{(n)}$ is $\pm\sin$ or $\pm\cos$ then $|c^{(n)}(y)|\le 1$
so
$$|f^{(n)}(x)|\le\int_0^1t^n\,dt=\frac1{n+1}.$$
I'll leave it to you to prove equality cannot occur.

Comment: Great solution! Btw, equality does occurs for $n$ even at $x=0$.

Comment: why ? $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\int_0^1\cos(tx)\,dt.$$

Comment: @Almot1960 , $x\in\Bbb R$ is a parameter and $\cos(xt)$ is a function of $t$, hence $\displaystyle\int_0^1\cos(xt)dt=\frac{\sin(xt)}x\Bigg|_0^1=\frac{\sin(x)}x$

Answer (score 1):

See that,
$$\frac{\sin x}{x} =f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-itx} dt$$

Then 
$$|f^{(n)}(x)| =\left|\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} (-it)^ne^{-itx} dt\right|  \le\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} |t|^n dt=\int_0^1t^n\,dt=\frac1{n+1}.$$