# $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, prove that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, inequality

This is a homework question.

> Let $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. I
>   have to prove that
>
> $$|f^{(n)}(x)|\le \frac{1}{n+1}$$
>
> where $f^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative of $f$.

I started to do a few derivatives:

$f^{(1)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}(x \cos x-\sin x)$

$f^{(2)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^3}((2-x^2) \sin x-2x\cos x)$

$f^{(3)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^4}(3(x^2-2) \sin x-x(x^2-6)\cos x)$

$f^{(4)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^5}(4x(x^2-6)\cos x + (x^4-12x^2+24)\cos x)$

I noticed that in denominator, there is always $x^{n+1}$ (because there is $x$ in denominator of $f$), but I couldn't spot a pattern for the numerator that would help me prove the inequality. Can I get a hint or a clue, please?

Comment: That is Problem 3 from the Bulgarian IMC 2014. Solutions here: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2014/IMC2014-day2-solutions.pdf.

Answer (score 12):

I will assume (since it's not specified) that $n$ is a non-negative integer.

**Claim:** For $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ and any non-negative integer $n$, we have:

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^xu^n\cos\left(u+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\,du$$

*Proof:* I will prove this by induction. The case $n=0$ is obvious:

$$f^{(0)}(dx)=f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\cos u\,du$$

Now assume it is true for some positive integer $n \geq 1$. Then, integrating by parts:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{(n+1)}(x)&=(f^{(n)})'(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{n+2}}\left(-(n+1)\int_0^xu^n\cos\left(u+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)+x\cdot x^n\cos\left(x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{n+2}}\left[-u^{n+1}\cos(u+\frac{n\pi}{2})\bigg|_0^x+\int_0^xu^{n+1}(\cos\left(u+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right))'\,du+x^{n+1}\cos(x+\frac{n\pi}{2})\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{x^{n+2}}\int_0^xu^{n+1}\cos\left(u+\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2}\right)\,du
\end{aligned}
$$

Claim proved. Now, the inequality follows immediately:

$$|f^{(n)}(x)|=\left|\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^xu^n\cos\left(u+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\,du\right|\leq \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^xu^n\,du=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Note that with the substitution $u=xy$, $\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^x u^n \cos\left(u+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\,du$ becomes $\int_0^1 y^n\cos\left(xy+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\,dy$, which might simplify the induction step. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2496305/42969.

Comment: @MartinR, Yes, I've seen your initial link to AOPS. I overcomplicated some the form of $f^{(n)}(x)$, as I was looking mainly at the numerator (probably influenced by the OP's work) and I didn't see it can be written in a more simple form.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion:

Try proving the Liebniz rule for differentiating the product of two functions on $\mathbb R$:

$$
(fg)^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x),
$$
and apply this to $f(x) = 1/x$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$ to show that
$$
\left|\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{(n)}\right| \le n!|x|^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{|x|^k}{k!}.
$$
Now try to use this to show the inequality you want.

---

**Edit:** This likely isn't enough to show the inequality on its own, as the bound we get still blows up at least like $1/|x|$ on the right-hand side as $x \to 0^+$. We aren't taking advantage of the cancellations in the sum over $k$, which evidently matter here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be helpful.  The RHS goes to $\infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool: Good point, we need to take more advantage of the cancellations in the sum to prove the inequality. I'll leave the answer as I think it's instructive to see that merely using the triangle inequality isn't enough here.